# How to get the frequency in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table (table_1) like this (I have simplified it)

```
   code   |    description   |    season    
----------+------------------+--------------
   500    |      info 1      |    fall    
   500    |      info 4      |    fall    
   500    |      info 8      |    fall    
   500    |      info 1      |    winter
   300    |      info 1      |    spring
   400    |      info 1      |    fall
```

And I want a table like below, where I have the frequency of codes in each season

```
  season  |  Number of Unique Codes  
----------+------------------------
   fall   |           2      
  winter  |           1           
  spring  |           1
```

So far I have this:

```
SELECT 
    season, 
    count(DISTINCT code) AS "Number of Unique Codes"
FROM table_1
WHERE code IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY season
ORDER BY code desc;
```

However, I am running into a few issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is on the `ORDER BY`, change your `ORDER BY` to sort by the alias created.

```
SELECT 
    season, 
    count(distinct code) AS "Number of Unique Codes"
FROM table_1
WHERE code IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY season
ORDER BY "Number of Unique Codes" DESC;
```